# Serilog Seq Output Template

Tags: serilog, seq-logging, getseq

I am new to Serilog and to Seq.  Sorry for the beginner question.

I want to have an output template that seems to be available in Serilog for the Console, but I can't seem to configure it in the WriteTo.Seq parameters.

Am I missing something or is this not available or is there another way to do this?

I was hoping to create a template constant and keep the format all in one place.

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seq uses signals with tagged properties for this.

1. Pick an event that has a property you want to show beside the message,
2. click the green "tick" to "Show as tag", and then
3. save the resulting signal so that you can apply it when you want to show the property inline.

The signal can be set as a default for your user account in (your username) > Preferences.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'll give it a shot.